# How can I keep the changes of my personal remote branch up to date with master?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-push, git-pull

This question is pretty much a continuation of this one: [git rebase master then push origin branch results in non-fast-forward error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8948964/git-rebase-master-then-push-origin-branch-results-in-non-fast-forward-error)

I have a personal local and remote feature branch named `dan`.  I've been working on it for a very long time and my coworkers have been committing to `origin/master` while I work on it.

If I do a `git pull --rebase` on `master`, `master` looks just how I like.  But my `dan` and `origin/dan` seem to have been created from where `master` used to be, not where it currently is.

I can temporarily solve this by doing `git rebase master dan`.  But then `origin/dan` will stay where it is.  If I try to `git push` on `dan`, I'll get an error (non-fast-forward).

This is pretty painful to deal with and I'd like to know what my options are.  In the end, I'd like it to **look** like I started with only a local `dan` branch that I did a `git rebase master dan` to, *then* I did a `git push origin dan` for the first time.  But, this is just a preference and if there is a smarter way to work and it doesn't even up looking that way, I'd be interested in using that instead.

The easiest solution for me so far as been to do all the rebasing I described above, delete these remote branches then recreate them from my local environment.  But, I don't feel comfortable with this process at all.  Besides, tomorrow someone may be working on my remote branch and then this won't be an option anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution remains to merge `master` to `dan` after updating `master`.

That allows you to push `dan` without having to deal with a non-fast-forward push error.

Yes, `origin/dan` will still start from "where `master` were", but that simply reflect from how long you have been working with this `dan` branch.

Comment: OK, are there any other options?  Like, is there a way I can `rebase origin/master origin/dan`?  Not even sure if that would accomplish a good result, but I'd like to know all my options.