# Git branch is always ahead

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-branch

I have a master branch and a development branch.
I'm currently in my development branch.

When I do `git push` I get the following suggestions:

```
fatal: The upstream branch of your current branch does not match the name of your current branch.  To push to the upstream branch on the remote, use
git push origin HEAD:master

To push to the branch of the same name on the remote, use
git push origin development
```

So I type `git push origin development` to push to the development branch. But I simple want to type `git push` to push to the current branch (development).

When I type `git status` I get this message:

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 26 commits.
```

So I did a pull request from development to master and merge the development branch into the master branch. But I still get the message "Your branch is ahead of ... ".

What am I doing wrong over here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you created your development branch you somehow set it to track `origin/master` instead of `origin/development`.

Run `git branch -vv` to see your branches and which upstream branches they are tracking.

You can correct the upstream setting for the development branch with:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/development development
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply.

Comment: What does it actually mean if the track is set to origin/master ? @Duncan

Comment: @DennisPerremans: for information about a branch's upstream setting, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122245/what-is-a-git-upstream or my rather long answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42328493/why-do-i-have-to-set-upstream-of-new-branch-i-create-locally