# Adding remote upstream to git repo on bit bucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

In case of GitHub, I added a remote named `upstream` to pull in latest changes to my forked repo using:

```
git remote add upstream git@github.com:<original_author_name>/<productname>.git
```

Here, `git@github.com:<original_author_name>/<productname>.git` is displayed on my github dashborad, Once I forked the repo.

But in case of Bitbucket, I always see my forked repo location but not the original source from where I fork it from. Now how can I find the location of original repo which I could add as remote - upstream to pull in latest changes from original I forked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that information (the upstream repo address from which you have forked your own BitBucket Git repo) is *really* not available anywhere, try at list a **[pull request](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Forking+a+bitbucket+Repository#ForkingabitbucketRepository-Step-by-StepExample%E2%80%93NowthePullRequest)**.

The pull request screen should display the candidate upstream repo name (that you can click to see its address).

[image: BitBucket pull request]

Answer (score 5):

Simply add it this way:

```
git remote add upstream git@bitbucket.org:YOUR-PROJECT-NAME.git
```

Check out this article for more info:
https://blogs.atlassian.com/2013/07/git-upstreams-forks/

Answer (score -2):

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch name you are working in locally  that matches the remote branch name>

git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/alui-git-feature1
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer. Posting code-only answers on old questions that already have other answers is not helpful.