# GitHub: Add a fork reference to a repository

Tags: github, git-fork

I have my own github repository that I want to fork with a new name because it's the 99% the same code, but will have some small changes for separate functionality.

Details:

- `eggers/dt-breeze` Is a typescript declaration file for breeze using Q.Promise
- `eggers/dt-breeze-angular` Is a typescript declaration file that swaps out Q.Promise for ng.IPromise

I didn't see a way to fork my own repository, so I created just created a separate repo, and just pushed the original code with changes to the new repo, but I would prefer to have a fork reference.

I saw this question: [Add Github fork to existing repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210273/add-github-fork-to-existing-repository) from two years ago, but was hoping that there was an update.

Comment: Why don't you use a seperate branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution remain a [branch within the repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3772759/6309), as [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21488569/github-add-a-fork-reference-to-a-repository/21495737#comment32438786_21488569) by [musicmatze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1391026/musicmatze).

Fork doesn't exist for one's own repo (and you [can't have two repos with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9658243/6309)): you can clone, and add an upstream remote as you would with a fork ([see this gist](https://gist.github.com/frebro/1834845)), but you won't benefit from the pull request mechanism.

The only other solution would be to create a second GitHub account, and use it to (truly) fork repos from the first account.